# Restricting certain page functionality or user interface to authenticated users in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I am using `Asp.Net/C#` to build an application.I am using `Forms Authentication`.I have a requirement such that many of my `authenticated (not anonymous) users` are restricted to certain page functionalities or user interface.I guess the `Login Control` could be used for only `Authenticated vs Anonymous` users.So my question is when I know that certain page component is to be hidden from particular authenticated users , how do I go about it.Do you think I need to use this on the page_load event to hide the components for the pages which have such requirements.

```
// Is this Tito visiting the page?
string userName = User.Identity.Name;
if (string.Compare(userName, "Tito", true) == 0)
 // This is Tito, SHOW the Delete column
 FilesGrid.Columns[1].Visible = true;
else
 // This is NOT Tito, HIDE the Delete column
 FilesGrid.Columns[1].Visible = false;
```

Are there better approaches to accomplish this.Any help is much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use the Membeship User class and [RolePrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprincipal.aspx) to separate the users.

```
if(HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Level1"))
{
    FilesGrid.Columns[1].Visible = true;
}
else
{
    FilesGrid.Columns[1].Visible = false;
}
```

So you make and place your user in different membership names, and then you show them different controls that are depend on the membership role.

Some links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprincipal.isinrole.aspx

Comment: so basically if I am to restrict functionalities of certain pages I will have to check it on the page_load itself , right?Declaratively I cant do it , is it a proper way.

Comment: I think that you can do anywhere that is return correct, but think that the IsInRole is costly in time, so you can cache it in local variable if you like to call it many times in a page.

Comment: @freebird check the links that I have place, the last one, have similar sample code.

Comment: thanks a lot I will check those links and incase of any further assistance I will get back to you

Answer (score 1):

You also need to know that, when you just hide a control, it's base64 encoded value is still present in the viewstate. The client is able to read it.

The client can also read which hidden control triggers an action. And nothing prevents a "smart" client from triggering this action.

So :

- restricted access values should not be bound to the controls, if you don't want to display it (prerender is not called on not visible controls. So doing your binding in prerender is a good habit)
- you should always add another access control check inside your event handlers, to see if the call is authorized

Comment: interesting, how ever you simple can disable viewstate for this control. And must close viewstate for this control to not eat space.

Comment: Indeed, best practice should be to set the control's visibility to false, disable it's viewstate, and not bind it ( and always recheck in event handlers )